# "error: cannot find symbol" Symbol is inside a Switch statement

Tags: java, object, switch-statement

Here's my code that the error points to:

```
shipX = shipOne.getX();
```

EDIT2: Specifically it cannot find shipOne.

The Ship object, shipOne, is initialized inside a Switch statement not ten lines prior to the above code. I'm fairly certain that the error is appearing due to the object being initialized inside the Switch statement, and I don't know what to do about that. There are a total of eight Ship objects that are initialized via a loop and as such the above code needs to either be in a Switch statement or an If statement, both of which I'm sure would cause the same error. Is there an exception I can throw or something that would cause my program to run? The Ship objects *do* get initialized 100% of the time so there's no worry there.

EDIT: I was asked for the rest of the code so here it be:

(This isn't the entirety of it, as you can't see the return statement but the remainder isn't relevant to my problem).

```
public static String[][] createFleet()
  {
  //Initialize Variables
     //Ship Variables
  boolean isHoriz = true;    //Is true if ship is Horizontal, false if Vertical
  char ID;
  int posX = 0;              //Origin of the ship (x coordinate [row])
  int posY = 0;              //Origin of the ship (y coordinate [column])
  int size = 0;              //Either 2, 3, or 4
     //Associated Variables
  Random randomGen = new Random();          //Random number generator
  String[][] board = new String[10][10];    //Gameboard, populated with ships
  int orientationRand = 0;                  //If 0, Ship Horizontal. If 1, Ship Vertical
  int posRand = 0;                          //Assigned to posX or posY
  int sizeRand = 0;                         //If 0 <= x < 10,   size = 2
                                            //If 10 <= x < 40,  size = 3
                                            //If 40 <= x < 100, size = 4

      //Create Ships
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
     //Size
     sizeRand = randomGen.nextInt(100);
     if (sizeRand < 10)
     {
        size = 2;
     }
     else if (sizeRand < 40)
     {
        size = 3;
     }
     else size = 4;
     //Orientation & Position
     orientationRand = randomGen.nextInt(2);
     if (orientationRand == 0)
     {
        //Orientation
        isHoriz = true;
        //Position (horizontal)
           //x position
        switch (size)
        {
           case 2:
              posRand = randomGen.nextInt(9);
              posX = posRand;
              break;
           case 3:
              posRand = randomGen.nextInt(8);
              posX = posRand;
              break;
           case 4:
              posRand = randomGen.nextInt(7);
              posX = posRand;
              break;
        }
           //y position
        posRand = randomGen.nextInt(10);
        posY = posRand;
     }
     else
     {
        //Orientation
        isHoriz = false;
        //Position (vertical)
           //x position
        posRand = randomGen.nextInt(10);
        posX = posRand;
           //y position
        switch (size)
        {
           case 2:
              posRand = randomGen.nextInt(9);
              posY = posRand;
              break;
           case 3:
              posRand = randomGen.nextInt(8);
              posY = posRand;
              break;
           case 4:
              posRand = randomGen.nextInt(7);
              posY = posRand;
              break;
        }
     }

     //Assign Size, Orientation, and Position to each ship
     switch (i)
     {
        case 0:
           ID = 'A';
           Ship shipOne = new Ship(posX, posY, size, isHoriz, ID);
           break;
        case 1:
           ID = 'B';
           Ship shipTwo = new Ship(posX, posY, size, isHoriz, ID);
           break;
        case 2:
           ID = 'C';
           Ship shipThree = new Ship(posX, posY, size, isHoriz, ID);
           break;
        case 3:
           ID = 'D';
           Ship shipFour = new Ship(posX, posY, size, isHoriz, ID);
           break;
        case 4:
           ID = 'E';
           Ship shipFive = new Ship(posX, posY, size, isHoriz, ID);
           break;
        case 5:
           ID = 'F';
           Ship shipSix = new Ship(posX, posY, size, isHoriz, ID);
           break;
        case 6:
           ID = 'G';
           Ship shipSeven = new Ship(posX, posY, size, isHoriz, ID);
           break;
        case 7:
           ID = 'H';
           Ship shipEight = new Ship(posX, posY, size, isHoriz, ID);
           break;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Outside the `switch`, any variable initialized in it is out of scope, that's why you're getting `cannot find symbol`. You should perhaps declare `shipOne` before the switch.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us where the relevant variables are declared and initialized, as well as precisely which symbol (`shipX`, `shipOne` or `getX`) could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, 'ID' variable is not getting declared anywhere. You must declare variable before using it.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. It's declared further up, I'll add that in there.

Comment: Then I don't see any issue with the posted code. You need to paste exception stack trace and further code as well to identify the exact reason for failure.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the objects to null before the switch or if statements. I think this should solve your problem.

It will be possible to provide a better solution if the entire code was posted.

Comment: Was the **Ship** class imported properly?

Comment: Show the exception stack trace.